# SQL ROW TO SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is my sql query how can I convert it to sqlalchemy, I already have the tables linked with foreign keys.

```sql
select listaproduccion.id, estado.name, orquestador.name, comentario.name, tipo.name,responsable.name, compania.name
from listaproduccion 
inner join estado on listaproduccion.estado_id=estado.id
inner join orquestador on listaproduccion.orquestador_id=orquestador.id
inner join comentario on listaproduccion.comentario_id=comentario.id
inner join compania on listaproduccion.compania_id=compania.id
inner join tipo on listaproduccion.tipo_id=tipo.id
inner join responsable  on listaproduccion.responsable_id=responsable.id;
```

I tried this, but it gives me an error:

```py
def get_list(db: Session):
    return db.query(
        model.ListaProduccion,
        model.Estado,
        model.Compania,
        model.Orquestador,
        model.Tipo,
        model.Responsable,
        model.Comentario
        ).join(ListaProduccion, ListaProduccion.estado_id, 
        ListaProduccion.compania_id,
        ListaProduccion.orquestador_id,
        ListaProduccion.tipo_id,
        ListaProduccion.responsable_id,
        ListaProduccion.comentario_id
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.estado_id) == Estado.name
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.compania_id) == Compania.name
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.orquestador_id) == Orquestador.name
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.tipo_id) == Tipo.name
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.responsable_id) == Responsable.name
        ).filter(str(ListaProduccion.comentario_id) == Comentario.name
        ).all()
```

How can I solve that?[The error I encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ur1.png)

Comment: Please do NOT use caps lock for your problem description. Format code as code and don't post images of code / tracebacks etc.

Comment: It says to use select_from. There's some example code in the documentation that looks similar to what I think you want: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.select_from